# Store targets as collections that handle logic operation

Tags: sql, encoding, collections

I think my title is kinda unclear but I don't konw how to tell that otherwise.

#### My problem is:

We have users that belong to groups, there are many types of groups and any user belong to exaclty one group for each type.

Example: With group types A, B and C, containing respectively the groups (A1; A2; A3), (B1; B2) and (C1; C2; C3)
Every User must have a list of groups like [A1, B1, C1] or [A1, B2, C3] but never [A1, A2, B1] or [A1, C2]

We have messages that target to certain groups but not just a union, it can be more complex collection operations

Example: we can have message intended to [A1, B1, C3], [A1, *, *], [A1|A2, *, *] or even like ([A1, B1, C2] | [A2, B2, C1])

(* = any group of the type, | = or)

Messages are stored in a SQL DB, and users can retrieve all messages intended to their groups

How may I store messages and make my Query to reproduce this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be to encode both the user groups and the message targets in a (big) integer built on the powers of 2, and then base your query on a bitwise `AND` between user group code and message target code.

The idea is, group 1 is 1, group 2 is 2, group 3 is 4 and so on.

**Level 1:**

*Assumptions:*

- you know in advance how many group types you have, and you have very few of them
- you don't have more than 64 groups per type (assuming you work with 64-bit integers)
- the message has only one target: `A1|A2,B..,C...` is ok, `A*,B...,C...` is ok, `(A1,B1,C1)|(A2,B2,C2)` is not.

*Solution:*

- Encode each user group as the corresponding power of 2
- Encode each message target as the sum of the allowed values: if groups 1 and 3 are allowed (`A1|A3`) the code will be `1+4=5`, if all groups are allowed (`A*`) the code will be `2**64-1`
- you will have a `User` table and a `Message` table, and both will have one field for each group type code
- The query will be `WHERE (u.g1 & m.g1) * (u.g2 & m.g2) * ... * (u.gN & m.gN) <> 0`

**Level 2:**

*Assumptions:*

- you have some more group types, and/or you don't know in advance how many they are, or how they are composed
- you don't have more than 64 groups in total (e.g. 10 for the first type, 12 for the second, ...)
- the message still has only one target as above

*Solution:*

- encode each user group and each message target as a single integer, taking care of the offset: if the first type has 10 groups they will be encoded from 1 to 1023 (`2**10-1`), then if the second type has 12 groups they will go from 1024 (`2**10`) to 4194304 (`2**(10+12)-1`), and so on
- you will still have a `User` table and a `Message` table, and both will have one single field for the cumulative code
- you will need to define a function which is able to check the user group vs the message target separately by each range; this can be difficult to do in SQL, and depends on which engine you are using
- following is a Python implementation of both the encoding and the check

```
class IdEncoder:
    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.grouplimits = {}
        offset = 0
        for i,size in enumerate(sizes):
            self.grouplimits[i] = (2**offset, 2**(offset + size)-1)
            offset += size

    def encode(self, vals):
        n = 0
        for i, val in enumerate(vals):
            if val == '*':
                g = self.grouplimits[i][1] - self.grouplimits[i][0] + 1
            else:
                svals = val.split('|')
                g = 0
                for sval in svals:
                    g += 2**(int(sval)-1)
                if i > 0:
                    g *= self.grouplimits[i][0]
            print(g)
            n += g
        return n

    def check(self, user, message):
        res = False
        for i,size in enumerate(self.sizes):
            if user%2**size & message%2**size == 0:
                break
            if i < len(self.sizes)-1:
                user >>= size
                message >>= size
        else:
            res = True
        return res

c = IdEncoder([10,12,10])
m3 = c.encode(['1|2','*','*'])
u1 = c.encode(['1','1','1'])
c.check(u1,m3)
True

u2=c.encode(['4','1','1'])
c.check(u2,m3)
False
```

**Level 3:**

*Assumptions:*

- you adopt one of the above solutions, but you need multiple targets for each message

*Solution:*

- You will need a third table, `MessageTarget`, containing the target code fields as above and a FK linking to the message
- The query will search for all the `MessageTarget` rows compatible with the `User` group code(s) and show the related `Message` data

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking about something that looked like this but I didn't know how to encode groups belongings & intersections in the same number

Answer (score 0):

So you have 3 main tables:

- Messages
- Users
- Groups

You then create 2 relationship tables:

- Message-Group
- User-Group

If you want to limit users to have access to just "their" messages then you join:
User > User-Group > Message-Group > Message

Comment: Okay but, in practice, how should I make my Query ? Imagine my group are [A1, B2, C1], is there a way to make a request without looking for every partitions of my set of groups ?

Comment: Can you explain what your query is trying to achieve? All users who should get a specific message, all messages that a specific user will get, or something else?